# Selenium Webdriver for Python: get page, enter values, click submit, get source

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Alright, I'm confused. So I want to scrape a page using Selenium Webdriver and Python. I've recorded a test case in the Selenium IDE. It has stuff like

```
Command    Taget
click      link=14
```

But I don't see how to run that in Python. The desirable end result is that I have the source of the final page.

Is there a run_test_case command? Or do I have to write individual command lines? I'm rather missing the link between the test case and the actual automation. Every site tells me how to load the initial page and how to get stuff from that page, but how do I enter values and click on stuff and get the source?

I've seen:

```
submitButton=driver.find_element_by_xpath("....")
submitButton.click()
```

Ok. And enter values? And get the source once I've submitted a page? I'm sorry that this is so general, but I really have looked around and haven't found a good tutorial that actually shows me how to do what I thought was the whole point of Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the IDE. I just write my tests or site automation by hand.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
print browser.page_source
```

You could put that in a script and just do `python wd_script.py` or you could open up a Python shell and type it in by hand, watch the browser open up, watch it get driven by each line. For this to work you will obviously need Firefox installed as well. Not all versions of Firefox work with all versions of Selenium. The current latest versions of each (Firefox 19, Selenium 2.31) do though.

An example showing logging into a form might look like this:

```
username_field = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=text]")
username_field.send_keys("my_username")
password_field = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=password]") 
password_field.send_keys("sekretz")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=submit]").click() 
print browser.page_source
```

This kind of stuff is much easier to write if you know css well. Weird errors can be caused by trying to find elements that are being generated in JavaScript. You might be looking for them before they exist for instance. It's easy enough to tell if this is the case by putting in a time.sleep for a little while and seeing if that fixes the problem. More elegantly you can abstract some kind of general wait for element function.

If you want to run Webdriver sessions as part of a suite of integration tests then I would suggest using Python's unittest to create them. You drive the browser to the site under test, and make assertions that the actions you are taking leave the page in a state you expect. I can share some examples of how that might work as well if you are interested.